# How to teach JAXB to locate classes in another project's .jar?

Tags: eclipse, jaxb, classpath

I am having trouble teaching JAXB to locate classes in a .jar file located in an other Eclipse project.

We are developing several web applications. Each application is a separate Eclipse project which eventually is packaged as a separate OSGi plugin which is then deployed to our server runtime.

The services that each application provides is specified using WSDLs. Since all services are using several common data structures, we moved those definition into a separate schema which is located in a "Shared" project and all WSDLs import that schema using an import statement like:

```
    ...
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="SharedTypes.v1_1.xsd"
            schemaLocation="../Shared/SharedTypes.v1.1.xsd">
        </xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema> 
    ...
```

i.e. they reach out of their own project ('..') and peak into the "Shared" project to import that schema.

The XML<=> Java bindings generated from that shared schema are saved to a .jar called "xsd.v1.1.sharedtypes.jar" which is placed in the /libs-folder of project "Shared".
That jar contains all classes corresponding to the types defined in the schema. An element, say, 'X' is compiled into a corresponding class "xsd.v1.1.sharedtypes.X". This .jar is declared as being exported from the "Shared" OSGi bundle.

The referencing OSGi bundles import this bundle, i.e. they declare "Shared" as a dependency.

The problem arises, when we try to generate the XML<=> Java bindings from the WSDL's in each project. There we always get a compile error in which the Eclipse JAXB wizard declares that it can't compile the classes it just generated from the WSDLs because it cannot find the classes that are contained in that shared .jar file.

But that .jar *DOES* contain the missing classes. It is also declared as being exported by the "Shared" plugin. And that plugin is being imported into the Applications' plugins. So these class *should* be visible at compile time, but obviously the JAXB-compiler sees that differently!

Any idea, how one can teach JAXB to include the exported .jar's of referenced OSGi plugins into the compilation's classpath when creating the XML-binding code?

Hope I could make myself clear...

M.

Comment: There may be some misunderstanding but generating Java source code from XML Schema files does not need to be aware of classes, not in a .jar nor elsewhere. Also, an XML "element X" is never compiled into a class X; it is XML Schema *types* that produce Java classes.

Comment: Re. Elemen vs. type: correct! My mistake - apologies. Re. the generation of Java bindings not needing to be aware of jar: this might in principle be correct, however, the JAXB "wizard" built into eclipse generates these into a temp directory and then directly tries to compile the generated bindings into a .jar (plus the sources into a second .jar). If anything fails during the process (like said compilation errors), then the whole process is aborted and effectively no bindings are generated. So, in this specific case: in *needs* to be aware of classes and .jars.